# php : multi-sort a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to **multi**-sort a **multi**-dimensional array. Here's a sample of my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [level] => beg01
            [start] => 09/10
            [finish] => 15/11
            [other] => blah blah
            [things] => blah blah
            [quite] => blah blah
            [a lot] => blah blah
            [actually] => blah blah
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [level] => beg01
            [start] => 01/10
            [finish] => 10/11
            [other] => blah blah
            [things] => blah blah
            [quite] => blah blah
            [a lot] => blah blah
            [actually] => blah blah
        )
........ 
}
```

I want the result to be sorted by the key '**level**' and among each level, I want the items to be sorted by the key '**start**'. Like this:

```
level 1 : 01/01
level 1 : 01/02
level 1 : 02/03

level 2 : 01/02
level 2 : 02/02
level 2 : 03/02
....
```

so far here's what I did: I pass my array twice trough this function:

```
function sort_one($arr,$index) {
                $b = array();
                $c = array();
                foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
                    $b[$key] = $value[$index];
                }
                asort($b);

                foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
                    $c[] = $arr[$key];
                }

                return $c;
}
```

with index *level* and *start*. I get two new arrays $by_level and $by_date.

then I multisort them:

```
array_multisort($by_level, $by_date);
```

It works almost but some elements are not in place so I think I am doing something wrong.

**edit:** Found a working solution:

```
$sort = array();
foreach($query_result as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['level'][$k] = $v['level'];
    $sort['start'][$k] = $v['start'];
}
array_multisort($sort['level'], SORT_ASC, $sort['start'], SORT_ASC,$query_result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in one pass by using `usort` with a callback which compares the level first, then compares the start only if the levels are equal:

```
usort($query_result, function($lhs, $rhs) {
     if ( $lhs['level'] == $rhs['level'] ) {
           return strcmp($lhs['start'], $rhs['start']);
     } else {
           return strcmp($lhs['level'], $rhs['level']);
     }
 });
```